# Add HtmlAgility Pack And Abot Web Crawler to Project

Tags: web-crawler, html-agility-pack

I Use "Abot" Version 1.2.3.1 but when I add "Html Agility" version 1.4.6.0 to project I get this error :

> Error 38  Assembly 'Abot, Version=1.2.3.1, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'HtmlAgilityPack, Version=1.4.7.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bd319b19eaf3b43a' which has a higher
>   version than referenced assembly 'HtmlAgilityPack, Version=1.4.6.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bd319b19eaf3b43a'

Comment: So then use HtmlAgilityPack 1.4.7.0

Comment: There Is`t HtmlAgilityPack 1.4.7.0.http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: Looks like the [trunk version](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Trunk/HtmlAgilityPack/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs) is 1.4.7, maybe the author was enlisted directly to the source code?

Comment: I build last version 1.4.7 and add to my project.Now Abot not working :[System.MissingFieldException] = {"Field not found: 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument.OptionMaxNestedChildNodes'."}

Comment: Looks like Abot is using some funky, perhaps customized/unreleased version/branch of agility pack?  How frustrating!  I'd contact the author.  I doubt anyone on SO can help you.

Comment: Have you tried to add the references via NuGet? I am using Abot 1.2.3.1 and HtmlAgilityPack 1.4.7.0 in the same project too. Both Dlls managed by NuGet without problems.

Comment: Yes.I Do.NuGet installed HtmlAgilityPack 1.4.6.0 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I install HtmlAgilityPack from NuGet Before Abot and problem solved!

```
1-
PM> Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack
2-
PM> Install-Package Abot
```

Comment: this works when installing Boilerpipe (or any package referencing HAP <=1.4.9), but fails with Unfluff.Net (using HAP >= 1.4.9.5). @Thorgeir's answer works for both

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old but I just ran into this issue. That is, Abot did not work when I had added the latest version of HAP. But the workaround is simple, just use the `CSQueryHyperlinkParser` to parse links. Like so:

```
var crawler = new Abot.Crawler.PoliteWebCrawler(config, null, null, null, null, new Abot.Core.CSQueryHyperlinkParser(), null, null, null);
```

This solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Abot uses a patched version of html agility pack since it would crash the process on certain types of html pages. See the issue documented here...

https://code.google.com/p/abot/issues/detail?id=77&can=1&q=htmlagilitypack

There is an issue on github to investigate if this was still a problem with the nuget version of html agility pack (which i'm pretty sure there is). So until the nuget version will not crash the host process Abot will like keep it's patched version of html agility pack.

https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fsjdirect%2Fabot%2Fissues%2F25&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNEpS2q4AuuejXdc3F8P2cVB-VtSSQ

Comment: What's the status of this issue? Or is there other alternatives?

Comment: Html agility pack still has this issue. Abot v1.5 may just use CsQuery as the default for link parsing since it does not suffer from this issue. I might even remove Html Agility Pack completely to remove the dependency.

Comment: Issue is still there as of last week. See the latest failed build by searching on [this page](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/sjdirect/abot/build/1.5.1.17) for the text "Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException". This test does not fail on a machine with lots of cpu and memory but a minimal build server crashes hard.